# how to use a gitflow hotfix branch

Tags: git, git-flow

We started using Gitflow for our branching model.
But we are not sure how to use hotfixes.
Do we have to use 1 hotfix branch for a hotfix release (meaning multiple fixes in 1 branch) or do we have to use 1 branch for every hotfix.
So if there are 10 bugs, we have 10 hotfix branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reference to this article by [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), following points can be derived:

- *Hotfix* branches are created for bugs in production releases.
- This branch is used as patch for next release cycle.

From these points it can be understood that **all the bugs** for a production release should be resolved in a single hotfix branch.

> **NOTE:** Care should be taken that after all the production bugs are resolved, the updated code is merged back to the develop and master branch. After merge make sure the *hotfix* branch is deleted. The develop branch can then be used to generate next release in the release cycle.